# Birkas Kohanim when wife is a niddah

Tags: kohen-priest, niddah, birchas-kohanim

I remember seeing somewhere that a kohen whose wife is a niddah should not recite the birkas kohanim. Does anyone know where this is cited? I don't beileve anyone practices this anymore.

Answer (score 8):

This is cited by [Raavad](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_ben_David) in his commentary to Tamid (end, s.v. He'chelu):

> ובספר מקצועות מצאתי כתוב היכא דאיכא נדה בביתא דכהן אסור אסור ליה למסיק לדוכן כל אימת דאיתא בנדתה דחייש דלמא נגע במידי דנגעה היא ואתי לאטמויי דאמר רבי יודן כל כהן שנושא את כפיו ואמו או אשתו או בתו טמאה ונכנס הוא באותו בית שנדה  לשם הרי תפילתו על ישראל תועבה ואף גורם לזרעו שיאבד מהעולם ולא עוד אלא שאינו מוציא את ישראל ידי חובתן ועליו הכתוב אומר ובפרישכם כפיכם אעלים עיני מכם וכי היכי דאסור ליה לכהן למעייל לביתיה שמונח ביה מת כך אסור ליה למיעל בביתא דאיתא נדה בגווה ואי אייחד לה אדרונה ולא נפקיה מינה כל ימי נדותה שפיר דמי

[Here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14304&st=&pgnum=509) is an online source, and here is the source as it appears in the 
standard Romm edition of the Talmud.

[image: Raavad]

Comment: Notably, he doesn't restrict it to the man's wife as the asker here did.

Comment: @msh210 Good point. Indeed, since the concern is about contamination the inclusion should follow.

Comment: But nobody takes chairs to the mikveh anymore!  They're just as tamei after she becomes pure! ( I assume מידי דנגעה היא refers to mishkav, moshav, and merkav because otherwise how would it make him tamei?)

Answer (score 5):

Piskei Teshuvot 128:92 quotes a discussion and recommends being machmir, whereas Yalkut Yosef 128:87 recommends not.

Answer (score 4):

The *Raavad* at the end of *Mesechta Tamid* quotes the *Sefer Hamiktzo'os* (assumed to be authored by *Rabeinu Chananel*): When there is a niddah in the home of a cohen he may not ascend the *duchan* [for Birkhas cohanim]' as long as she remains a niddah, since we are concerned that he may touch something which she has touched and he will become *tamei*. Rav Yudan said "Any cohen who lifts his hands [recites birkhas kohanim] and his mother, or his wife, or his daughter are a niddah' and he enters the house where the niddah is, his prayers for Yisrael are *toevah* (abomination), and he also causes his children to be lost from the world. And not only this, but he cannot be *motzi* any Jew with his obligation. And in reference to him the passuk states (Yeshayahu 1:15) And when you lift up your hands, I will turn My eyes away from you. and f he sets aside a room for her, and she does not leave there as long as she is a niddah it is fine.

The *Pri Chadash* (OC 128:30) quotes the *Raavad*, and he adds: These things should not be publicized since they are not *ikar hadin* (the mainstream law), and [it is better to] leave the people to transgress unknowingly rather than knowingly.

Thr Raavad says that for some of the things listed above in the Sefer Hamiktzo'os refer only to *Baalei Nefesh*,  (people on a higer spiritual level), but that which he says about birkhat kohanim is applicable to everyone... but it is a wonder if we say that even today (when the is no Bais Hamikdash) the words of Rav Yudan would stil be applicable. At the end of his words he says: *Vehamachmir Yisbarach*. (One who is stringent in this will be blessed.

The sefer *Shailos Uteshuvos Beis Ephraim* says that this may be the reason why (outside of Israel) Birkhat Kohanim is not recited daily. And after quoting the *Raavad* and the *Pri Chadash* he adds who can not be concerned about this as the gaon Rabeinu Chananel, author of *Sefer Hamiktzo'os* who was widely known for his great strength (in Torah) quoting in the name of Rav Yudan who was one of the *Amoraim* says that his prayers are *toevah*, and he also causes his children...etc. and who is the man who wanting a bracha instead causes a klalah (curse). And although the Pri chadash says not to publicize it I must do so so that people should not speak out against it, so let everyone know that so is written in the *Sefer Hamiktzoos* and it is quoted in the *Raavad*, and also in the *Sefer Machzik Bracha* (of the *Chida*).

(More to come...)

Comment: It's very unclear to this reader what part of this is quoting whom.

Answer (score 4):

[R. Eliezer Waldenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_Waldenberg) has a responsum which discusses this. He cites the Sefer Hamiktzo'os (mentioned in other answers) and then quotes a bunch of sources (some cited in the above answers as well) that we are not concerned about this.

**Shu"t Tzitz Eliezer 10:8**

> עוד רגע אדבר ואודיע לכתר"ה דבנוגע לדברי המקצועות שמביא השערי דורא שכ"ג
>   מציינו בדבריו ודן בביאורו אביא לו בזה מה שמובא עוד בשמו בהראב"ד סוף
>   תמיד ומה שהראב"ד מבאר כונתו דהראב"ד שם מביא בשם ס' המקצועות שכותב
>   דהיכא דאיכא נדה בביתא דכהן אסור ליה למיסק לדוכן כל אימת דאיתא בנדתה
>   וכו' דא"ר יודן כל כהן שנושא את כפיו ואמו או אשתו או בתו טמאה ונכנס הוא
>   באותו בית שנדה לשם הרי תפלתו על ישראל תועבה וכו' יעו"ש שמביא כמה
>   מאמרים מאד מפתיעים והראב"ד מתקשה בהם ומפרש דלא אמרו אלא לבעלי נפש ורק
>   בנוגע לישא כפים לכהנים כותב דלכ"ע אסירי וכותב להסביר הטעם משום דלנדה
>   וזבה סמך הכתוב והזהרתם את בני ישראל וכו' (בטמאים) [בטמאם] את משכני וכו'
>   לפיכך צריך לעשות הרחקה טובא לכל מה שנוהג במקדש כגון ברכת כהנים והקרבת
>   קרבנם שהם מעשה כהונה שאע"פ שברכת כהנים נוהגת בגבולין מ"מ עיקרה היא
>   במקדש ומפני שתימה לומר שאפי' בזה"ז יהי' נוהג דבר זה לפיכך אמר ג"כ
>   שגורם לזרעו שיאבד מפני שברכה שאינה ראוי' נהפך לקללה וכו' יעו"ש ביתר
>   אריכות ויש בהם להשלים בהרבה גם להבנת הדברים המובאים בשערי דורא בשם ס'
>   המקצועות
>
> ודברי ס' המקצועות כפי שהובאו בראב"ד תמיד מובאים גם בפרי חדש או"ח סי'
>   קכ"ח סק"ל אך מסיים לאחר מיכן וכותב וז"ל ודברים אלו אין לפרסמם דלא הם
>   מעיקר הדין והנח לישראל שיהיו שוגגין ואל יהיו מזידין עכ"ל ויעוין בפרמ"ג
>   במ"ז שם ס"ק כ"ו שמעיד ג"כ שהעולם אין נזהרין בכל זה ע"ש ועיין עוד באשל
>   אברהם (להגאון בעל דעת קדושים ז"ל) שהביא זאת מהפר"ח ונו"נ בזה ולסוף
>   סיים ביתר על האמור בפר"ח וכתב גם י"ל שדברי חז"ל בזה הוא רק בזמן שהיה
>   להם אפר פרה והיו נזהרים בטהרה היו עושים הרחקה מחשש נגיעה במשכב נדה
>   משא"כ עכשיו שאנו בבחינת מה שאמר הכתוב השוכן אתם בתוך טומאתם כו' אין
>   שום קפידא בנו בזה עיי"ש והתבוננתי שלדברים אלה מטים גם דברי החיד"א ז"ל
>   במחזיק ברכה סי' קכ"ח אות י' וביותר בקו"א שם אות ה' עיי"ש ויעוין מ"ש
>   בזה אריכות דברים גם הח"ס ז"ל בחידושיו למס' שבת ד' פ"ב ובתשובותיו
>   בחאו"ח סי' כ"ג ע"ש